# How to revert initial object after mutated inside Jest's test method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have read the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) but I didn't found any sample code that explaining my goals. This is my current code;

These tasks, I used for match the expected object on the `validateRegular()`'s `return` with [`.toMatchObject` method](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tomatchobjectobject).

```js
// This is the function for validate the object.
const { validateRegular } = require('../src/options/validate')

// This is just a function that return an object if validateRegular() return invalid.
const { errorResponse } = require('../src/helpers')

// Initial mock data object.
const regularData = {
  email: 'adit@gmail.com',
  password: '123456',
  confirmation_password: '123456'
}

describe('options -> validate: true || Object', () => {
  describe(`validate -> type: "regular"`, () => {
    
    // This test() is running well.
    test(`Validated payload`, () => {
      const mock = validateRegular(regularData)
      expect(mock).toMatchObject(regularData)
    })

    // This test() is running well.
    test(`If don't have an email`, () => {
      regularData.email = null
      const mock = validateRegular(regularData)
      expect(mock).toMatchObject(errorResponse(
        'Email is empty',
        'No email'
      ))
    })

    // I got "failed" on this because the previous test(). I set the email to null and not revert it back into first initial data object.
    test(`If don't have a password`, () => {
      regularData.password = null
      const mock = validateRegular(regularData)
      expect(mock).toMatchObject(errorResponse(
        'Password is empty',
        'No password'
      ))
    })

  })
})
```

Please help me to find out how the best method to handle these tests. Should I mutate back the data object's prop on every tests that I run? Like this;

```js
test(`If don't have a password`, () => {
  regularData.email = 'adit@gmail.com' // Like this...
  regularData.password = null
  const mock = validateRegular(regularData)
  expect(mock).toMatchObject(errorResponse(
    'Password is empty',
    'No password'
  ))
})
```

This running well, but I think this is not cool code to write. I'm sure if any correct method for handle this case to init the object again inside [GLOBAL methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api) -> `.beforeEach()` or `.afterEach()`, but I'm not found the idea after read the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout) yet.

Comment: Don’t mutate objects between tests. I prefer to duplicate code in tests (shock horror I know!)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yea man, I just don't want to repeat my code. Because DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. Just curious what another method that better to handle case like this.

Comment: I don’t use dry in tests.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Hmm, Interesting.. Make sense enough.

Answer (score 2):

Objects need to be reverted with a combination of `beforeEach` and `afterEach` only if they cannot be reset otherwise, i.e. when a global variable is mocked. In any other situation a fresh object needs to be retrieved. If an object originates from a module, a module can be reset and re-imported. If it's defined locally like `regularData`, it can be just redefined for every test that uses it:

```
let regularData;

beforeEach(() => {
    regularData = {
      email: 'adit@gmail.com',
      password: '123456',
      confirmation_password: '123456'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also simply make a copy of the object each time. This will fail strict equality, but `toMatchObject()` will work.

```
test(`If don't have an email`, () => {
  const mock = validateRegular({ ...regularData, email: null })
  expect(mock).toMatchObject(errorResponse(
    'Email is empty',
    'No email'
  ))
})
```